# Sublime Text - shortcut for setting the vertical selection

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

Since the beginning of the week I have to work with Debian, and one of the pbm I find with Sublime Text is that the vertical selection I used to use with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left click is catched by the OS (it selects the current window to move).

I tried to edit the key-binding file of Sublime Text, but I could not find the line corresponding to vertical selection.

Do you know where it is? How can I change the default shortcut for vertical selection?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are searching for:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085502/sublime-text-modifying-linux-mousemap-to-use-4th-mouse-button)

```
 ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap

[
    // Map column select to 4th mouse button.
    {
        "button": "button4",
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    }
]
```