# Sublime text bind mouse buttons to jump to cursor

Tags: sublimetext

I want to bind my forward and back mouse buttons (4, 5) to jump between previous cursor positions. I have my file

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap
```

My code is as such

```
[
  {
    "button": "button4",
    "command": "jump_back"
  },
  {
    "button": "button5",
    "command": "jump_forward"
  }
]
```

I have also tried

```
{
  "button": "button5",
  "modifiers" : [],
  "command": "jump_forward"
}
```

And even

```
{
  "button": "button5",
  "modifiers" : ["alt"],
  "command": "jump_forward"
}
```

But the default next / prev tab set-up is always used. Using the sublime default key bindings works however

```
"alt" + "-"
"shift" + "alt" + "-"
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085502/sublime-text-modifying-linux-mousemap-to-use-4th-mouse-button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Linux:

**Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap**

```
{ "button": "button8", "command": "jump_back" },
{ "button": "button9", "command": "jump_forward" }
```

**Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap**

```
{ "button": "button4", "command": "jump_back" },
{ "button": "button5", "command": "jump_forward" }
```

Comment: Note that SublimeText expects an *array* of bindings.  If you've just created a mousemap file, you'll need to wrap the contents in `[` and `]`.

Comment: There's no mousemap file by default, and no menu item to edit one. However, the LaTeXTools plugin has a command-palette entry to create one. Search for 'mouse' in the palette if you have the plugin installed.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you add these settings to a MOUSEMAP and not a KEYMAP.

If you open the folder of your key preferences and add create a file like this:

**`Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`**

```
[
    {
        "button": "button4",
        "command": "jump_back"
    },
    {
        "button": "button5",
        "command": "jump_forward"
    }
]
```

Just make sure the filename conforms to whatever your keymap filename (e.g. replace WINDOWS with UNIX if that's how your keymap is named).

Comment: The issue was that my mouse buttons were not 4 and 5, but 8 and 9. I found the correct button codes thanks to the link @Muhammet linked

Comment: @myol Thanks. It's the same for me on Linux.