# How to configure 5 buttons mouse in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings, preferences

I have a mouse with 5 buttons, how can I configure these buttons to do specific tasks in Sublime Text 3. Like when `button4` does `Build` and `button5` does `Build With...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of Sublime Text, the mouse actions are configured by what are known as `mousemap` files (that have an extension `.sublime-mousemap`). You can have generally 2 variants of these files :-

- `Default.sublime-mousemap`: This will define mouse actions for any platform.
- `Default ($platform).sublime-mousemap`: This will define mouse actions for a specific platform, where `$platform` is any **one** of `Windows`, `Linux` or `OSX` depending on your operating system.

You can view the default shipped mousemap files by using `View Package File` from the command palette and searching for `mousemap`.

In order to define your own mouse actions (or override any existing actions), you have to create a file by the name of `Default.sublime-mousemap` in the `User` directory (to get to this directory, select `Preferences -> Browse Packages ...` from the main menu) for platform independent override (or `Default ($platform).sublime-mousemap` for platform dependent overrides depending on your OS).

Once that's done, here is some basic knowledge about mousemap files (Note that there is no official or community documentation about mousemap files so everything is based on experimentation and what the dev's have said about such files).

Here are the meaning of some keys in mousemap files :-

- **button**: This defines the name of the button. For example, **button1** refers to the left mouse button & **button2** defines the right mouse button. Similarly, you can have **button3**, **button4**. **button5** etc. I am not sure how many such button names actually exist. Also for the scroll wheel, you have **scroll_up** for upward scroll movement & **scroll_down** for the opposite behavior.
- **modifiers**: This is a list of modifier keys like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> etc. For example, `["alt"]`, `["ctrl", "alt"]`. When you define a modifier list, all the modifier keys listed should be pressed simultaneously and then pressing/releasing the corresponding button triggers some action.
- **command**: This defines the command to be executed when the corresponding button is **released** after being pressed. If this command takes any arguments, you can have an **args** key for it.
- **press_command**: This defines the command to be executed when the corresponding button is **pressed**. If this command takes any arguments, you can have a **press_args** key for it.
- **count**: The number of times you have to press the corresponding button to trigger the action (by action, I mean execute the corresponding **command**/**press_command**)

> NOTE:
> You can define both **command** and **press_command** if you wanted to.

Let's look at some examples :-

File name :- `User/Default.sublime-mousemap`

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button2",
        "modifiers": [],
        "press_command": "echo",
        "press_args": {
            "message": "I am pressed"
        },
        "command": "echo",
        "args": {
            "message": "I am released"
        },
    }
]
```

Here, the right button (**button2**) is bound to the built in **echo** command. If you now right click, the default behavior would have been actually the opening of the context menu, but now we have **overriden** that behavior and now you can see the corresponding messages `{'message': 'I am pressed'}` or `{'message': 'I am released'}` in the console based on whether you have pressed or released after pressing.

For your case, you can have something like the following :-

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", // replace button1 with button4/5 because I don't have that many mouse buttons.
        "modifiers": ["alt", "ctrl", "shift"],
        "press_command": "undo",
    }   
]
```

Now, when you now press **button1** (while holding down <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> simultaneously), the **undo** command should be executed. You can set **modifiers** to an empty list if you don't want that.

As for build, if you mean executing the most recent build system, replace **undo**, with **build**.

As a parting bonus tip, if you want to disable any button actions, just use the command **noop**.

Example :-

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "modifiers": [],
        "press_command": "noop",
    }   
]
```

This will disable **button1** and now you can't drag select anymore ;-) So be careful.

Hopefully, this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank You very much. I really appreciate this. Can you tell me where can I find all the list of command values and press_command values. I will look it up. But if you have any good sources please include. Thnaks :-)

Comment: @an4s911 I believe you can use any command name for both command/press_command (note that they both are same, the only difference being what is triggered depending on the state of the mouse button). Here is a nearly complete list of commands available in ST with the args :- https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html#about-paths-in-command-arguments

Comment: Can you please explain that. I didn't quite understand that. You said it is depending on the state of mouse.

Comment: If I press the left mouse button (button1), then press_command is executed. If I release the same button after pressing, then command is executed. Try out the example given above to understand it.

Comment: Oh OK. Thank You very much for you valuable time.

Comment: This answer [Sublime Text modifying Linux mousemap to use 4th mouse button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085503/2102457) will be useful to some people.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info @matt